# Read Remote Machine Certificate

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate2

We can use the `X509`store to load the store and find the certificates in local machine but how to do the same for a certificate sitting on remote server?

I know we can configure a network account to have permissions on the certificate in remote machine but how to use this network account to read certificate details?

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection results = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "CertName", false);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this `X509Store` overload: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07btzah(v=vs.110).aspx

where you can specify remote server path: `\\RemoteServerName\My` in the `storeName` parameter.

Comment: I have been parked in the same page from morning but I didnot know that we could refer to remote server like \\[Machine]\StoreName. Thank you

Comment: Can we also specify different domain in front of remote server name?

Comment: yes, you can specify FQDN of the remote server. But make sure if authentication and permissions are configured properly between domains.

Comment: Hi @CryptoGuy , i tried to give machine name/remote server name which is my colleague machine but i didn't succeed. I've given name in such format \\Machinename\My      , If i try to access the same machine using run command than it works fine for me . i am using C# code base Please advise

Comment: But this doesn't work for "CurrentUser". Any hints how to get it??

Comment: No, this doesn't work for remote users for security reasons.

Comment: Works fine! Tip: in C# string, remember to escape the inverse bar like "\\\\RemoteServerName\\My"